# Using quotes in variables of a crontab job

Tags: cron

I'm trying to get a past date inside a cron job using something like this. But the `DATE` variable is always empty.

```sh
DATE=date -d "$date -1 days -1 months" +%Y-%m
* * * * * /bin/echo "Date: $($DATE) Test" >> /tmp/crontab.log 2>&1
```

I know how tricky crontab is thanks to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/339814/how-do-you-set-a-date-variable-to-use-in-a-log-for-crontab-output) with good answers, but the problem here doesn't seem to be the `%` sign, because the code above works fine:

```sh
DATE=date -d @2147483647 +%Y-%m
* * * * * /bin/echo "Date: $($DATE) Test" >> /tmp/crontab.log 2>&1
```

But if I use quotes, then the job again can't get the date.

```sh
DATE=date -d"@2147483647" +%Y-%m
* * * * * /bin/echo "Date: $($DATE) Test" >> /tmp/crontab.log 2>&1
```

I tried replacing quotes with single quotes, double quotes, escaping the quotes, but none of this options solved the problem. And I need quotes to specify the `"$date -1 days -1 months"` part. Is there a way to do this in crontab without creating an external script?

*CentOS 7 and crontab (cronie-1.4.11-23.el7.x86_64)*

Answer (score 0):

The issue has nothing to do with `cron` but with variable expansion within `$()`. The `date` command called in the subshell `$()` doesn't see a parameter `-d "$date -1 days -1 months"` but multiple params instead: `-d` `"$date` `-1` `days` `-1` `months`. You probably want to use `$(eval $DATE)` instead.